# Expected Value of Random Vector

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, covariance

I've got this exercise but cannot really understand the "logic" behind it.

I have a random vector $t$ where $t \thicksim N(0, \sigma^2 I_n)$ and I've been asked to give: $E[t_i]$, $E[t_i^2]$ and $E[t_k t_p]$ with $k,p=1,...,n$ and $k \neq p$.

Since we are dealing with a N distribution, the expected value is 0. 
So the first two $E$ should be 0, regarding the third one I would be able to work with it in the case of two independent vectors via a double sum but here I don't know what to do...

I'm sure it's a pretty straightforward exercise but I'm completely stuck.

My statistics course was in the discrete and continue "world", vectors and matrices are still pretty new to me.

Thanks for any suggestions and help!

Comment: You need to add the self-study tag. As a hint: Pay attention to the covariance matrix of this multivariate normal distribution. It is diagonal with all the variance terms identical & the off diagonal terms (covariance terms) equal 0. What is the implication of 0 covariance for a multivariate normal? It should be easy for you to see how this determines the expected moments that you are asked to compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t$ is a multi-variate normal with mean vector $0$, i.e. $E[t_i]=0$, and covariance matrix $\Sigma=\sigma^2I_n$. Covariance matrix is defined as $\Sigma_{ij}=\operatorname{cov}(t_i,t_j)=E[t_it_j]-E[t_i]E[t_j]=E[t_it_j]$. Since the matrix is diagonal, off diagonal entries are $0$, i.e. $E[t_it_j]=0$ for $i\neq j$. If $i=j$, then $\Sigma_{ii}=\sigma^2=E[t_i^2]$.

Comment: Thank you very much @gunes, you have been extremely clear!